# React leaflet draw on image

Tags: react-leaflet, react-leaflet-draw

I am trying to use the drawing function of react-leaflet Where not drawing a map, but drawing on a picture
Right now I have to use the function  inside   do you have any suggestions? Or if it can't be done

```
<Map center={center} zoom={ZOOM_LEVEL} ref={mapRef} >
            < Image />
          <FeatureGroup>
            <EditControl
              position="topright"
              onCreated={_onCreate}
              onEdited={_onEdited}
              onDeleted={_onDeleted}
              draw={{
                rectangle: false,
                polyline: false,
                circle: false,
                circlemarker: false,
                marker: false,
              }}
            />
          </FeatureGroup>
          </Map>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use MapContainer and inside it you have to use ImageOverlay and to ImageOverlay you have to give the image url or a base64 image.

```
 <MapContainer
      // ref={mapRef}
      className="markercluster-map"
      center={[-500, 550]}
      zoom={-2}
      minZoom={-18}
      maxZoom={18}
      style={{ height: "70vh", width: "70%" }}
      crs={CRS.Simple}
    >
      <ImageOverlay
        url={imageUrl}
        bounds={bounds}
        opacity={0.8}
        zIndex={10}
        scale={1}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <FeatureGroup
          ref={(featureGroupRef) => {
            onFeatureGroupReady(featureGroupRef);
          }}
        >
          <EditControl onEdited={onEdited} onCreated={onCreated} />
        </FeatureGroup>
      </ImageOverlay>
    </MapContainer>
```